# how to adding new key with multiple values inside of it in python dictionary

Tags: python

i have dictionary like this :

```
country = { 
           'spain': { 'capital':'madrid', 'population':46.77 },
           'france': { 'capital':'paris', 'population':66.03 },
           'germany': { 'capital':'berlin', 'population':80.62 },
           'norway': { 'capital':'oslo', 'population':5.084 } 
         }
```

how to adding new key and multiple values to become like this (i adding country indonesia as new feature in last index dictionary

```
country = { 
           'spain': { 'capital':'madrid', 'population':46.77 },
           'france': { 'capital':'paris', 'population':66.03 },
           'germany': { 'capital':'berlin', 'population':80.62 },
           'norway': { 'capital':'oslo', 'population':5.084 },
           'indonesia' : {'capital':'jakarta', 'population':250}
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
country['indonesia'] = {'capital':'jakarta', 'population':250}
```